# NestJS App won't use the .env or configService PORT. Always starts on port 3000 no matter what

Tags: nestjs, dotenv, nestjs-config

I have a barebones NestJS app where all I have done is add a `.env` file with `PORT=3001` as the content and then modified my `main.ts` according to the [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-in-the-maints):

```js
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {bufferLogs: true});
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const PORT = configService.get('PORT');
  app.listen(PORT);
}
bootstrap();
```

My AppModule:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true}),
    UsersModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

When I run the app, it always runs on port 3000. It never runs on port 3001. What is going on???

Comment: Is your .env file placed at the project root directory? Also, take into account that if you have an environment variable (for example you are exporting export PORT=3000 in your shell) this variable takes precedence over the .env file configuration

Comment: .env is at directory root. No shell vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that `npm run start:dev` (aka `"start:dev": "nest start --watch"`) doesn't actually rebuild! I had to kill the process, run `npm run build` to update my dist folder, and then run `npm run start:dev`. What a headache.

Comment: `start:dev` _should_ be rebuilding. I do notice that you are not `await`ing the `app.listen()`, but I don't know if that would change anything. I'd be very interested to see the reproduction with `start:dev`/`nest start --watch` not rebuilding